# Difference between \pagenumbering{} and \renewcommand{\thepage}{}

Tags: macros, page-numbering

Command `\pagenumbering` is defined like this

```
\def\pagenumbering#1{%
  \global\c@page \@ne \gdef\thepage{\csname @#1\endcsname
   \c@page}}
```

So it reset page numbering and define `\thepage`, `\pagenumbering{arabic}` can be achieved with

```
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
```

Why in most cases we use the first method and  we do not use the second form to redefine  page numbering although it gives us more control and capabilities than the first ? is there disadvantages to use the second method ?

Comment: Having the `\pagenumbering` macro is handy because people may forget that they would need to run both `\setcounter{page}{1}` *and* `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}`.

Comment: Also `\pagenumbering` does `\gdef`, while `\renewcommand` does (non-global) `\def`, so scoping rules apply

Comment: @Mico but using `\renewcommand{\thepage}` allow us to obtain more  numbering form like for example `Page 1`, `Page 2`, ....

Comment: In the `book` document class, `\pagenumbering{roman}` is used in the definition of `\frontmatter` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` is used in the definition of  `\mainmatter`.

Comment: When asking "why"-type questions regarding the choices made in the design of TeX and LaTeX document, it's worth keeping in mind that these choices were frequently based more on personal preferences and prior experiences than on the outcomes of explicit optimization routines. In short, answers to why-type questions about the design of TeX and LaTeX tend to involve lots of anecdotes. Speaking for myself, I have no problem at all with this; however, others may find it mildly disappointing -- especially if they were assuming that these choices were the outcomes of some grand optimization effort.

Comment: I find for numbering format command like `\renewcommand{\thefigure}`, `\renewcommand{\theequation}`,   `\renewcommand{\thesection}`, `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}`, but with page numbering we find `\pagenumbering`!!! Why we do not use the same way like previous numbering?